# Is there any possibity to import a list of numbers into python?

Tags: python, editor

I want to import a list of numbers into python as an array.....The data is the output of an Monte Carlo Code and is written as a dat. file.

The output looks like this:

```
0.7882E+00   0.9888E+01   0.1381E+02   0.1572E+02     
0.1742E+02   0.1872E+02   0.2087E+02   0.2734E+02   
.
.
.
```

I already googled a lot but I don't find an solution

Thank You!

Comment: Is your list of numbers in a text file?

Comment: @Sheldon: I _think_ that's unlikely, given its `.dat` extension, but knowing the file format is essential (and missing) information.

Comment: @martineau: Good point! I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to load data stored in a text file, you can use the numpy `loadtxt` method:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.loadtxt(fname = "myfile.txt")
```

**[EDIT]** If your data are stored in a `.dat` file you can use the numpy `fromfile` method to load them in an array.